# Putting conditions in matching texts in awk

Tags: awk

I have two files that I am trying to find their matching sections and modify  accordingly.

```
file1.txt

1 101 A9D  1 6  123  BCX 
2 298 JKB  2 7  234  CCC 
3 299 7CD  3 9  345  DDD 
4 329 T6T  3 12 387  DDE



file2.txt

1 6  123  .  BCX 
2 7  234  .  CCC 
4 23 990  .  DDD 
8 62 397  .  XC9
```

If the `1st,2nd,3rd and 5th` columns of `file2.txt` is the same with `4th,5th,6th,7th` of file1.txt, I only want to keep the `7th` column of `file1.txt`.

If they don't match, then it should print the lines in `file1` with dashes and commas without removing any information.

Expected output is :

```
1 101 A9D  BCX 
2 298 JKB  CCC 
3 299 7CD  3,9,345-DDD 
4 329 T6T  3,12,387-DDE
```

I have tried to do :

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3,$5]=$5;next} (($4,$5,$6,$7) in a){print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$7;next} 1' file2.txt file1.txt
```

However I could not separate them with commas and dashes, and could not keep only the `7th` column of `file1.`

How can I print the 7th column of `file1.txt` if there is a wanted match, and all the columns if there is not the match wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    keyFmt = "%s,%s,%s-%s"
}
NR==FNR {
    key = sprintf(keyFmt,$1,$2,$3,$5)
    a[key]
    next
}
{
    key = sprintf(keyFmt,$4,$5,$6,$7)
    print $1, $2, $3, (key in a ? $7 : key)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
1 101 A9D BCX
2 298 JKB CCC
3 299 7CD 3,9,345-DDD
4 329 T6T 3,12,387-DDE
```

Answer (score 1):

If your actual Input_file(s) are same as shown samples then following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4,$5,$6,$7]=$4 OFS $5 OFS $6 "-" $7;b[$4,$5,$6,$7]=$1 FS $2 FS $3;next} (($1,$2,$3,$5) in a){print b[$1,$2,$3,$5] FS $NF;delete a[$1,$2,$3,$5];next} END{for(i in a){print b[i] FS a[i]}}'  OFS=, FILe1.txt  FILe2.txt
```

Adding a non one liner form of solution too now:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[$4,$5,$6,$7]=$4 OFS $5 OFS $6 "-" $7;
   b[$4,$5,$6,$7]=$1 FS $2 FS $3;
   next
}
(($1,$2,$3,$5) in a){
   print b[$1,$2,$3,$5] FS $NF;
   delete a[$1,$2,$3,$5];
   next
}
END{
   for(i in a){
      print b[i] FS a[i]}
}
'  OFS=, FILe1.txt  FILe2.txt
```

Output will be as follows:

```
1 101 A9D BCX
2 298 JKB CCC
3 299 7CD 3,9,345-DDD
4 329 T6T 3,12,387-DDE
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` one liner

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1FS$2FS$3FS$5]=$5; next} {if($4FS$5FS$6FS$7 in a)$0=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $7; else $0=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4","$5","$6"-"$7}1' file2 file1
1 101 A9D BCX
2 298 JKB CCC
3 299 7CD 3,9,345-DDD
4 329 T6T 3,12,387-DDE
```

I just added `$0=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4","$5","$6"-"$7` for your second part with `if-else`

You were quite close.